# How can I export a street material using procedural textures to Unity?

Tags: shaders, export, unity

I tried to make a road texture with puddles by this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e-S0DM5hlc. My problem is I can't bake the shaders, (puddles etc..) The first picture you can see the shader editior. In the second picture you can see how it looks in blender. In the third picture you can see how it looks in unity.

[image]
[image][image]![]

Comment: You can't bake the shaders because you don't know how to do it or what exactly is the problem? Because you cannot export things like math nodes, bump nodes, color ramps etc. to Unity. These are Blender-specific features. I'm not familiar enough with Unity to tell if you can somehow recreate them there, but certainly you cannot simply export the material in Blender and import it into Unity.

Comment: Hello, I bake the textures but after import in in unity the puddles and etc is gone. (You can see on the third picture). But if I can't export color ramp etc. to Unity how can I make a puddle for my road texture?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bake the Roughness map too, then in Unity switch the material shader type from "Standard" to "Autodesk" and maually add the Roughness map into the roughness slot. This will give you the puddles effect.

Comment: I put the Roughtness map into the roughness slot, but this not really loook like a puddle. https://ibb.co/wgf3j6H   https://ibb.co/pwfj86K You can see on these pictures.

Comment: Normal map is missing. The HDRI reflections also help to sell the puddles, so you will have to build some reflections in Unity too.

Comment: https://ibb.co/9NLb8SL  https://ibb.co/x19jRHk  https://ibb.co/c2xZ2dC https://ibb.co/w7tvdDh  It still doesn't look good. Any ideas?